# Restriction on label name of Jenkins build jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I just upgraded Jenkins to 2.263.2 version, then I have some build job take a long time to start a build, regarding the log below, I found

```
    2021-01-25 03:14:58.396+0000 [id=55] SEVERE  hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner#lambda$update$6: Unexpected uncaught exception encountered while processing agent ecsaws-ecs1||ecs2||ecs3||ecs4||ecs5-hmll4
hudson.model.Failure: ‘|’ is an unsafe character
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.checkGoodName(Jenkins.java:4029)
        at jenkins.model.Nodes.addNode(Nodes.java:139)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.addNode(Jenkins.java:2157)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.lambda$update$6(NodeProvisioner.java:256)
        at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1398)
        at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1275)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.update(NodeProvisioner.java:225)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.access$900(NodeProvisioner.java:64)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$NodeProvisionerInvoker.doRun(NodeProvisioner.java:823)
        at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:91)
        at out that this is restriction on label name.
```

I set the node label in build job as below
[image]

So I went to "Script Console" and run command: System.setProperty("hudson.model.LabelAtom.allowFolderTraversal", "true") , also tried to Reload Configuration from Disk, but the issue still occur

Something wrong or what might causing the issue?

Comment: looks like its because of the way your label names are defined, why dont you try some label name without special characters `||`

Comment: Yes, I know this is a security handerning in new version, but as Jenkins documentation, it can be disable by by setting the Java system property hudson.model.LabelAtom.allowFolderTraversal to true, but the issue still occur.
I have many build jobs using this special characters, so I'd like to disable this hardening instead of changing in all build jobs

Comment: I think you should try setting it at `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` or add the system property directly to the Jenkins java command it self and check after restart.